# GCP Bigquery Insertion takes too long

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am updating data in Bigquery table, table is very small having not more then 10 rows of data.

which have 3 fields [id,field1,field2]

when I run update query from portal it take 1 second, while when I ran same query from python code it take 3 seconds on local (2.5 seconds on GCP function)

Here is query :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field1= value1
WHERE id = any_random_id
```

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
connection_string = "bigquery://***"
client = bigquery.Client()
job = client.query(update_query)
job.result()
```

And now lets say I need to update 5 records at the same time, it takes more then 8 second?

Edit:

Is this time performance is normal like same query on PostgreSQL takes 1 second while here 8 seconds ?

Do I am doing something wrong? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Is it really a problem? Anyway, what is the region of your dataset? What is your own location?

Comment: Well, I don't know if you do things wrong or not... That depends what requirements do you have, context, scope, budget, time, and... why did you decide to use BigQuery first of all?

Comment: @al-dann I need to update those values from my dashboard using API, updating 4 records it take 8 to 11 seconds while with PostgreSQL it takes less then 1 second. As of now for this budget is not an issue time is most crucial. we are inserting high frequency IoT data in another table in the same dataset on which client has some ML models running, we just need to maintain devices address, for that small purpose, we cant maintain a new different database, so using bigquery. I hope it answer your question

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere for updating only 4 records it is taking 8 to 11 seocnds, I think it is too long for such a small table with not that complex query. Dataset and cloud function is in same location i.e. us-central1

Comment: My point was - BigQuery is different. Separate storage and processing, asynchronous jobs, etc. It takes time. It may take 5 seconds to update a few records, and 5 seconds to read a few hundred gigabytes of data... Cloud function might need to be started/initiated, if there is no 'alive' instance... It takes time. In your requirements, context, budget and project scheduler, it might be better to use something else, if the time for update is the most critical thing. Or read/update those line for your ML model from some other place.

Comment: @al-dann Thanks for suggestion. As of now read/update for ML Model can't be changed. This 8 seconds does not include the total API time, it is just to update records. so cloud function is not an issue. I got the idea, that insert/update can take time, it is not something that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, from my personal point of view, (regular) update of the BigQuery table - is already something wrong. However such operation is allowed, so for some people it might be OK in some situations. It is up to you.

Comment: Hi @Abhishekbhatia, where are you running your above code? Are you using the latest version of [bigquery api](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest)?

Comment: @kiranmathew `google==3.0.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==3.10.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.19.1` I'm using these version. Running the above code in cloud function.

Comment: Hi @Abhishekbhatia, Can you try the code mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows) for row insertion? For more information you can to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python).Let me know if it's helpful or not?.